# Error while iterating list

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, site-collection

I tried this:

```
var itemArray = [];

    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList =   clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('FlexMasterList');
    var oListItem;
    var i=1;
    var j=0;
        for(i=1;i<myTableArray.length;i++)
        {

            oListItem=oList.getItemById(myTableArray [i][0]);
            alert(oListItem.get_item('Claim_x0020_Identifier'));        
        }                                                   
}
```

but I am getting the following error:

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Did you checked the internal name your column `Claim_x0020_Identifier`

Comment: Please refer the link for How to: Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript. This will help you out - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeededCallback, failedCallback)` is missing from you code.

You will be able to access list data in `succeededCallback` function only.

Please refer [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx) link for you reference.

Comment: yes i have gone through the link you provided....the problem is : oList.getItemById( ); and listItemEnumerator object does not have this function

Comment: if  you can tell me how i can get element directly by id  without itertaing the list view using id then please help

Comment: @Shomit can you please post/update the code that you have tried after referring the msdn link So that we can help you in a better way.

Comment: i posting a new quetion with my code and this was my refernce: http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/batch-operations-using-javascript.html

Comment: hey buddy posted new plss help